# How to filter and display all products based on clicked categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help me with solution, I want to display products based on categories like this

```
 eg:  products
      -sarees
      -salwars
```

when I click on sarees I want to display all products related on sarees, and when I click on Salwars, I want to display all products related to salwars

Here is my code
**show.html.slim**

```
        li
        a href="#{shop_index_path}" 
          | Product  
          span.arrow ▼
        ul.sub-menu
         - @category.each do |cat|
          li
            a href="#" 
              =cat.name
```

my **productscontroller.rb**

```
def show
 @category = Category.all 
end
```

my model **category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end
```

model **product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: You can trigger a `change` event for category and send an `ajax` request to find the belonging products and replace.

Answer (score 0):

@sreena, I would first suggest make it work as simple as possible and only then add `AJAX` to the mix.

Let's say your routes file looks something like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
end
```

Change your `show.html.slim` to be `index.html.slim` and edit:

```
 ul.sub-menu
     - @categories.each do |cat|
      li
        = link_to cat.name, category_path(cat)
```

And your `products_controller.rb` to:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all 
end

def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

Now you have a basic `index` and `show` working!

After you've got that working `AJAX`ifying it is not a problem.

Comment: thank you for helping me, bt sorry it doesn't worked for me. i have no catagory controller , just iam adding cataory data through seeds.rb

Comment: it's great that you add through the `seeds.rb` but there should be a controller as well to handle the requests :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to have a nested controller for products under categories. Something like category/:category_id/products. So a GET on this route would directly search for all products under the supplied category. 
On the anchor tags you will then want to link to these products using

```
 - @category.each do |cat|
    li
      =link_to cat.name, category_products_path(cat), remote: true 

     #products
```

In the products controller, we define an index action

```
 def index
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @products = @category.products
 end
```

To display the products define products/index.js.slim

```
 $('#products').html('#{escape_javascript(render(@products))}');
```

And products/_product.html.slim partial

```
 li
   = product.name
```